# isn't it more concise and straightforward to declare a struct variable without 'struct' keyword?

Tags: c, struct

I'm new to C, sorry if my question sounds a little bit stranger.

We know that the struct is like:

```
struct struct_name {
   DataType member1_name;
   DataType member2_name;
   DataType member3_name;
   …
};
```

and we declare variable of a struct as:

```
struct  struct_name  var_name;
```

but I'm just thinking, isn't that more concise and straightforward to declare a struct variable without 'struct' keyword as:

```
struct_name  var_name;    //compile error unless the we use typedef for the struct
```

but from the compiler's perspectives, `struct_name` is all that the compiler needs to know. and using an analogy of class in high level programming languages like Java or C#, we declare class as

`class class_name {...}`

to declare an instance of the class, we just code:`class_name foo;`, we don't code `class class_name foo;`.

So why struct in C is designed to use `struct` keyword when declaring a struct variable?

Comment: In C this is simply a rule of the type system.  The same goes for other types such as `enum` and `union`.  You can use `typedef` to get around this.  In C++, you may omit the qualifying keyword when using the type.  Essentially, you're asking why C is different from languages that were created years after C.

Comment: By omitting `struct` you would save some typing but otherwise you don't gain much. At te same time you lose some clarity for the programmer. It takes a while of C programming to be able to weigh whether the advantage is greater than the disadvantage. The extra typing really isn't a problem.

Comment: @paddy Please make this an answer.

Comment: Re "*from the compiler's perspectives, struct_name is all that the compiler needs to know*", That's not true. That refers to a different, non-struct type which may or may not exist. Are you asking for the historical reasons why there are different namespaces for structs and for more basic types?

Comment: @thebusybee I left a comment instead of an answer largely because I'm not answering the final question of _why_ it's like this, nor am I answering the question in the title which seems like the kind of question that can only be answered by opinions.

Comment: @paddy Good point. So let's close this question because it is "opinion-based".

Comment: I weren't around when that was decided so I can only guess. My guess is: "To make it clear that the variable is a composite type". You can work around it using typedef. Some programmers argues that typedefs are bad because it hiddes that information which makes it "less concise" - however other programmers "love" typedefs. Pretty opinion based. Read the paragraph "Usage concerns" here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef

Comment: @thebusybee To me it seems the question is really two different questions. One (i.e. the title) is opinion based I think. The other (i.e. last sentence) is very specific but also harder to answer when you didn't design the language. Anyway - I agree that this should be closed. I'll go for "Needs more focus"

Comment: That's the way C is [C11 Standard - 6.2.3 Name spaces of identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.3)

Answer (score 1):

If we could say `foo x` rather than `struct foo x`, then the name `foo` could clash with some other type called `foo` that had been introduced by a `typedef`. This potential problem doesn't affect languages like Java, that don't allow new type names to be introduced except as classes.

The problem also doesn't affect C++, because using a type name created using `typedef` and a `class` or `struct` with the same name in the same scope is not allowed.

So, while C could, in principle, have allowed a `struct` variable to be declared without using the `struct` keyword, this would have prevented the use of a `typedef` type and `struct` with the same name.

How great a loss would that be? Probably not a huge loss. It isn't a loss that seems to be mourned by C++ developers, given the benefits.

In short, being able to declare a `struct` variable without a `struct` keyword in C would not have been entirely without consequences.

Comment: This isn't really the point. The rules in C mean that you can use a `struct foo` and a `typedef foo` in the same scope, should you wish. There's no ambiguity about which you mean because you have to use `struct` to denote the `struct`. In C++ we can use `Foo x` rather that `class Foo x` because a `tyepdef` for `Foo` would not be allowed in the same scope. And in Java, the problem never even arises, because types cannot be created _except_ as classes. The ability to write `Foo x` in C++ means we have to sacrifice a feature from C -- not that it was very useful.

Comment: @user694733 in most cases, you should avoid `typedef` for `struct` (or `union` or `enum`).  e.g. read https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.8/process/coding-style.html#typedefs)

Comment: @ensc -- I think that's a matter of opinion. I _always_ typedef `struct`s when I'm using them in a way that is analogous to Java or C++ classes. But, in any case, I'm not sure that's what's being asked here.

Answer (score 0):

To declare a variable without `struct` you have to use `typedef` in order to create a new type of variable:

```
typedef struct struct_name {
   DataType member1_name;
   DataType member2_name;
   DataType member3_name;
   …
}new_type_of_variable;
```

This new variable is a struct variable, now you can do this:

```
new_type_of_variable var_name;
```